# How to find duplicate values in array using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have some inputs which names is array in one form:

```
<input type="text" name="email[]" id="email" />
<input type="text" name="email[]" id="email" />
<input type="text" name="email[]" id="email" />
```

etc.

when I submit the form I need to check in jQuery if have a duplicated value in this inputs, can help me anyone?

thanks :)

Comment: An `id` ***must be unique within the document***.

Comment: @David Thomas, yes `id` also is unique in document

Comment: Look at what I said in my previous comment, then look at your HTML. Specifically the `id` attribute of *every* `input` element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
var values = $('input[name="email[]"]').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).toArray();

var hasDups = !values.every(function(v,i) {
  return values.indexOf(v) == i;
});

$('form').submit(function(e) {
   if (hasDups) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Also, ids should be unique like people are saying in the comments.

Comment: thank you for answer but `hasDups` always return true, i put diffrent emails but return true, why?

Comment: Right, I forgot...change to this `!values.every(function() {...`. Works fine now http://jsbin.com/ezinad/1/edit

Comment: hmm now always return false?

Comment: yes I check the demo, I change the values for example i put two time `three` and console return false!

Comment: the problem is in value, when i put the value in HTML is working fine but when i put in the text field and submit value comes empty

Comment: i found the solution for me and you help me very much thank you bro :)