# Generate an error if number is repeated in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql, asp-classic

I have a web form for admin purposes where the user can change the order that a group of records is shown on a webpage.

For example: A table (tblStuff) in a database has three fields:

```
ContentID, Content, RecordPosition
```

The table has, say, four records:

```
1, Guess what, 1
2, More stuff, 2
3, Some stuff, 3
4, That's right, 4
```

The SQL code is:

```
SELECT * FROM tblStuff ORDER BY RecordPosition ASC
```

The user can use the form to change the RecordPosition number so that the order can read:

```
3, Some stuff, 1
2, More stuff, 2
1, Guess what, 3
4, That's right, 4
```

So... How can I validate the form so that the same number isn't entered twice into the RecordPosition field?

Hope this makes sense.

Here's the whole page

```vb
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<!--#include virtual="/Connections/ENG.asp" -->
<%
' *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
MM_authorizedUsers=""
MM_authFailedURL="../default.asp"
MM_grantAccess=false
If Session("MM_Username") <> "" Then
  If (true Or CStr(Session("MM_UserAuthorization"))="") Or _
         (InStr(1,MM_authorizedUsers,Session("MM_UserAuthorization"))>=1) Then
    MM_grantAccess = true
  End If
End If
If Not MM_grantAccess Then
  MM_qsChar = "?"
  If (InStr(1,MM_authFailedURL,"?") >= 1) Then MM_qsChar = "&"
  MM_referrer = Request.ServerVariables("URL")
  if (Len(Request.QueryString()) > 0) Then MM_referrer = MM_referrer & "?" & Request.QueryString()
  MM_authFailedURL = MM_authFailedURL & MM_qsChar & "accessdenied=" & Server.URLEncode(MM_referrer)
  Response.Redirect(MM_authFailedURL)
End If
%>
<%
If Request.Form("action")="update" Then
  'Set variables for update
  Dim updateSQL, i
  Dim cContentID, cPositionNumber

'Loop through records on screen and update
For i = 1 To fFormat(Request.Form("counter")) 

'Create the proper field names to reference on the form
cContentID = "ContentID" & CStr(i)
cPositionNumber = "PositionNumber" & CStr(i)

'Create the update sql statement
updateSQL = "UPDATE tblContent SET PositionNumber=" & fFormat(Request.Form(cPositionNumber)) & " WHERE ContentID=" & fFormat(Request.Form(cContentID))

'Run the sql statement
Call sRunSQL(updateSQL)
Next

'Refresh page
Response.Redirect("record-order-modify-updated.asp")
End If

Function fFormat(vText)
  fFormat = Replace(vText, "'", "''")
End Function

Sub sRunSQL(vSQL)
  set cExecute = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  With cExecute
    .ActiveConnection = MM_ENG_STRING
    .CommandText = vSQL
    .CommandType = 1
    .CommandTimeout = 0
    .Prepared = true
    .Execute()
  End With
End Sub
%>
<%
Dim rsCharityDetails
Dim rsCharityDetails_cmd
Dim rsCharityDetails_numRows

Set rsCharityDetails_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsCharityDetails_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_ENG_STRING
rsCharityDetails_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblCharityDetails" 
rsCharityDetails_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rsCharityDetails = rsCharityDetails_cmd.Execute
rsCharityDetails_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim rsNavBar
Dim rsNavBar_cmd
Dim rsNavBar_numRows

Set rsNavBar_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsNavBar_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_ENG_STRING
rsNavBar_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblMainMenu WHERE MainMenuID <6  OR MainMenuID >7" 
rsNavBar_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rsNavBar = rsNavBar_cmd.Execute
rsNavBar_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim rsContent__smID
rsContent__smID = "1"
If (Request.QueryString("smID")   <> "") Then 
  rsContent__smID = Request.QueryString("smID")  
End If
%>
<%
Dim rsContent
Dim rsContent_cmd
Dim rsContent_numRows

Set rsContent_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsContent_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_ENG_STRING
rsContent_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tblContent.*, tblMainMenu.MainMenuName, tblSubMenu.SubMenuName, tblSubMenu.SubMenuID FROM (tblContent LEFT JOIN tblMainMenu ON tblContent.MainMenuID = tblMainMenu.MainMenuID) LEFT JOIN tblSubMenu ON tblContent.SubMenuID = tblSubMenu.SubMenuID WHERE tblContent.SubMenuID = ? AND tblContent.DisplayRecord =1 ORDER BY tblContent.PositionNumber" 
rsContent_cmd.Prepared = true
rsContent_cmd.Parameters.Append rsContent_cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 5, 1, -1, rsContent__smID) ' adDouble

Set rsContent = rsContent_cmd.Execute
rsContent_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim rsMenuList
Dim rsMenuList_cmd
Dim rsMenuList_numRows

Set rsMenuList_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsMenuList_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_ENG_STRING
rsMenuList_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT tblMainMenu.MainMenuID, tblMainMenu.MainMenuName, tblSubMenu.SubMenuID, tblSubMenu.SubMenuName FROM tblMainMenu INNER JOIN tblSubMenu ON tblMainMenu.MainMenuID = tblSubMenu.MainMenuID WHERE tblSubMenu.SubMenuID <> 6 AND tblSubMenu.SubMenuID <16 OR tblSubMenu.SubMenuID >19" 
rsMenuList_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rsMenuList = rsMenuList_cmd.Execute
rsMenuList_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim rsHeaderImage
Dim rsHeaderImage_cmd
Dim rsHeaderImage_numRows

Set rsHeaderImage_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsHeaderImage_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_ENG_STRING
rsHeaderImage_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MainMenuImage, MainMenuID FROM tblMainMenu" 
rsHeaderImage_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rsHeaderImage = rsHeaderImage_cmd.Execute
rsHeaderImage_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim navBar__numRows
Dim navBar__index

navBar__numRows = -1
navBar__index = 0
rsNavBar_numRows = rsNavBar_numRows + navBar__numRows
%>
<%
Dim rptContent__numRows
Dim rptContent__index

rptContent__numRows = -1
rptContent__index = 0
rsContent_numRows = rsContent_numRows + rptContent__numRows
%>
<%
Dim Repeat_MenuList__numRows
Dim Repeat_MenuList__index

Repeat_MenuList__numRows = -1
Repeat_MenuList__index = 0
rsMenuList_numRows = rsMenuList_numRows + Repeat_MenuList__numRows
%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">

<!-- disable iPhone inital scale -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

<title><%=(rsCharityDetails.Fields.Item("CharityName").Value)%> | English Website Administration</title>
<!-- main css -->
<link href="../../scripts/mfm-standard-stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link href="../scripts/mfm-standard-stylesheet_ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->

<!-- Admin css -->
<link href="../scripts/mfm-admin-stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="../../scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery NailThumb Plugin - any image to any thumbnail Examples and documentation at: http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb.php -->
<script src="../../scripts/jquery.nailthumb.1.1.js"></script>
<!-- Lightbox2 v2.51 by Lokesh Dhakar For more information, visit: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ -->
<script src="../../scripts/lightbox.js"></script>
<!-- Lightbox css -->
<link href="../../scripts/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="../tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script src="../tiny_mce/tiny-mce-mfm.js"></script>

<!-- html5.js for IE less than 9 -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- css3-mediaqueries.js for IE less than 9 -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body id="other">

<div id="wrapper">
<header class="innerWidth">
<!--#include file="includes/header-modify-record.asp" -->
</header>

<nav class="innerWidth">
<!--#include file="includes/navbar-modify-record.asp" -->
</nav>

<!-- pageContent -->
<div id="content" class="innerWidth">

<!-- Aside -->
<aside>

<h3>Record Order</h3>

<ul>
<% 
Dim txtOldHeading
txtOldHeading = ""
    While ((Repeat_MenuList__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rsMenuList.EOF)) 
If txtOldHeading = rsMenuList.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value Then
Else
txtOldHeading = rsMenuList.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value
%>
<li class="menuHeading"><%=(rsMenuList.Fields.Item("MainMenuName").Value)%></li>
<%
END IF
%>
 <li class="menuList">
 <% If (rsMenuList.Fields.Item("SubMenuID").Value) = "3" Then %>
     <a href="our-development-partners-record-order-modify.asp"><%=(rsMenuList.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></a>
 <% ElseIf (rsMenuList.Fields.Item("SubMenuID").Value) = "15" Then %>
     <a href="shop-record-order-modify.asp"><%=(rsMenuList.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></a>
 <% ElseIf (rsMenuList.Fields.Item("SubMenuID").Value) = "20" Then %>
     <a href="friends-of-mfm-record-order-modify.asp"><%=(rsMenuList.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></a>
 <% Else %>
     <a href="record-order-modify.asp?smID=<%=(rsMenuList.Fields.Item("SubMenuID").Value)%>"><%=(rsMenuList.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></a>
     <% End If %>
 </li>
 <% 
 Repeat_MenuList__index=Repeat_MenuList__index+1
 Repeat_MenuList__numRows=Repeat_MenuList__numRows-1
 rsMenuList.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
</ul>
</aside>
<!-- /Aside -->

<!-- Article -->
<article>
<% IF Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING") <> "" THEN %>
<h3><span style="font-size:small">Order/Re-order records for: </span><%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("SubMenuName").Value)%></h3>
<% 
Dim counter
While ((rptContent__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rsContent.EOF)) 
counter = counter + 1
%>
<form action="record-order-modify.asp" method="post" class="recordPosition">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" name="ContentTitle" colspan="2"><h2><%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("ContentTitle").Value)%></h2><input type="hidden" value="<%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("ContentID").Value)%>" name="ContentID<%=counter%>"></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" name="ContentData"><%
    Dim tmp
    tmp = rsContent.Fields.Item("ContentData").Value
    %>
        <% =LEFT(tmp, INSTR((tmp & "."), ".")) %>..
       </td>
      <% IF (IsNull(rsContent.Fields.Item("ContentImage").Value)) THEN %>
      <td width="140" align="center" valign="top" name="ContentImage"><img src="../images/system_images/red-x.png"></td>
      <% ELSE %>
      <td width="140" align="center" valign="top" name="ContentImage"><div class="nailthumb-container">
        <!-- Thumbnail Container -->
        <img src="<%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("ContentImage").Value)%>"> </div></td>
      <% END IF %>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><label>Current Record Position: <small class="brown" style="text-transform:none">(You may change it here)</small></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="PositionNumber<%=counter%>" tabindex="<%=counter%>" value="<%=(rsContent.Fields.Item("PositionNumber").Value)%>"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>
  <% 
  rptContent__index=rptContent__index+1
  rptContent__numRows=rptContent__numRows-1
  rsContent.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
<table align="center" class="positionButtons">
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="right"><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Update Positions" tabindex="<%=counter%>"></td>
<td width="50%" align="left"><input name="Reset" type="reset" value="Reset All Changes" tabindex="<%=counter%>"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="update">
<input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<%=counter%>">
</form>
<% ELSE %>
<h3>Select a listing to order/re-order using the list on the left.</h3>
<% END IF %>
</article>
<!-- /Article -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.nailthumb-container').nailthumb({width:125,height:125,fitDirection:'top center'});
    });
</script>

</div>
<!-- /pageContent -->

<div class="push"></div>
</div>
<!-- #wrapper -->

<footer class="innerWidth">
<!--#include file="includes/footer.asp" -->
</footer>

</body>
</html>
<%
rsCharityDetails.Close()
Set rsCharityDetails = Nothing
%>
<%
rsNavBar.Close()
Set rsNavBar = Nothing
%>
<%
rsContent.Close()
Set rsContent = Nothing
%>
<%
rsMenuList.Close()
Set rsMenuList = Nothing
%>
<%
rsHeaderImage.Close()
Set rsHeaderImage = Nothing
%>
```

As requested by Allende, here's the generated form code.

```
<form action="record-order-modify.asp" method="post" class="recordPosition">

  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" name="ContentTitle" colspan="2"><h2>Investing in people and the environment</h2><input type="hidden" value="15" name="ContentID1"></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" name="ContentData"><p>Madagascar is an environmental hotspot...
       </td>

      <td width="140" align="center" valign="top" name="ContentImage"><div class="nailthumb-container">
        <!-- Thumbnail Container -->
        <img src="/images/framed-images/mfm-website-(26).jpg"> </div></td>

      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><label>Current Record Position: <small class="brown" style="text-transform:none">(You may change it here)</small></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="PositionNumber1" tabindex="1" value="1"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>

  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" name="ContentTitle" colspan="2"><h2>The next generation</h2><input type="hidden" value="16" name="ContentID2"></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" name="ContentData"><p>Teaching Malagasy children to respect and nurture their environment is critical to the survival of Madagascar's biodiversity...
       </td>

      <td width="140" align="center" valign="top" name="ContentImage"><div class="nailthumb-container">
        <!-- Thumbnail Container -->
        <img src="/images/framed-images/mfm-website-(292).jpg"> </div></td>

      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><label>Current Record Position: <small class="brown" style="text-transform:none">(You may change it here)</small></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="PositionNumber2" tabindex="2" value="2"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>

  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" name="ContentTitle" colspan="2"><h2>Recognition for our work</h2><input type="hidden" value="17" name="ContentID3"></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" name="ContentData"><p>Our work over 2 decades with 73 villages surrounding the Reserve of Betampona recently gained recognition at an international conference held at the University of East Anglia...
       </td>

      <td width="140" align="center" valign="top" name="ContentImage"><div class="nailthumb-container">
        <!-- Thumbnail Container -->
        <img src="/images/framed-images/mfm-website-(56).jpg"> </div></td>

      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><label>Current Record Position: <small class="brown" style="text-transform:none">(You may change it here)</small></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="PositionNumber3" tabindex="3" value="3"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>

  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" name="ContentTitle" colspan="2"><h2>Adding value by adding forests</h2><input type="hidden" value="18" name="ContentID4"></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" name="ContentData"><p>Often the best way to protect an old forest is to plant a new one...
       </td>

      <td width="140" align="center" valign="top" name="ContentImage"><div class="nailthumb-container">
        <!-- Thumbnail Container -->
        <img src="/images/framed-images/mfm-website-(217).jpg"> </div></td>

      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left"><label>Current Record Position: <small class="brown" style="text-transform:none">(You may change it here)</small></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="PositionNumber4" tabindex="4" value="4"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>

<table align="center" class="positionButtons">
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="right"><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Update Positions" tabindex="4"></td>
<td width="50%" align="left"><input name="Reset" type="reset" value="Reset All Changes" tabindex="4"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="update">
<input type="hidden" name="counter" value="4">
</form>
```

Comment: Is your question about how to do validation is ASP or how to prevent duplicate value on MySQL side?

Comment: You need to look into MySQL's primary key & auto increment

Comment: This isn't really about not allowing duplicates in the table. The tables already use auto increment for the primary keys.

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML, (just the form code with the records) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you have form like this (notice all the inputs has the same class):

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action"someUrl">
    <input type="text" class="recordPosition"></input>
    <input type="text" class="recordPosition"></input>
    <input type="text" class="recordPosition"></input>
    <input type="text" class="recordPosition"></input>
</form>
```

You could do with jQuery something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $(".recordPosition").on("blur", function(){
     var allFieldsForOrder = $('.recordPosition');
     var count = 0;
     var i=0
    //console.log(allFieldsForOrder.length );
      while((i<allFieldsForOrder.length) && (count < 2)){
             if ($(allFieldsForOrder[i]).val()===$(this).val())
            {
             count++                 
            }
            i++;
     } 

     if (count==2){
        alert("A duplicated value"); return false;}
    }); 
 });
```

For the html you posted you can use this:
**Notice** I don't store the position of the  duplicated the value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //console.log($("input[type='text'][name^='PositionNumber'").length);
    $("input[type='text'][name^='PositionNumber'").each(function(){
         $(this).on("blur", function(){

         var allFieldsForOrder = $("input[type='text'][name^='PositionNumber'");
         var count = 0;
         var i=0

         while((i<allFieldsForOrder.length) && (count < 2)){
                if ($(allFieldsForOrder[i]).val()===$(this).val())
                {
                 count++                 
                }
                i++;
         }

         if (count==2){
            alert("A duplicated value"); 
         }

       });
    });
  });
```

**For the code above we assume you want to check for all the fields where the attribute name starts with the string "PositionNumber"**

I will try to reduce the code later, I think there's a shortest way to check if is duplicated the "RecordPosition" value, but need to test some ideas.

This will be your solution (one of them):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){


    $('form').on("submit",function(){
            var tempArray=[];
            $("input[type='text'][name^='PositionNumber'").each(function(){
                tempArray.push($(this).val());
            });

            var i=0;
            var duplicated=false;
            var currentElement;
            while((tempArray.length >= 0) && (duplicated==false)){                  
                //pop it out from the array
               currentElement = tempArray.pop();
               duplicated = tempArray.indexOf(currentElement)          

            }

            //after you can use "duplicated" to cancel the submit
            if (duplicated){                    
                alert("duplicated value:" + currentElement);
                return false;
            }

    });
  });
```

I shorter version:

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
 $('form').on("submit",function(){
         var tempArray=[];            
        var exists=0;
         $("input[type='text'][name^='PositionNumber'").each(function(){
             exists = tempArray.indexOf($(this).val());             
             if (exists>=0){                    
                 return false;//break the loop
             }
             tempArray.push($(this).val());                  
         });

         //after you can use "exist" to check if duplicated and retrieve the value to cancel the submit
         if (exists>=0){                   
             alert("duplicated value:" + tempArray[exists]);                
         } else{
             alert("no duplicated value:");
         }

        return false;            
 }); 
});
```

Comment: yw ! the code above can be improved (I;m pretty sure even if I don't know how), I have an idea for a shortest way to check for a duplicate value, can since I'm at work have no time to test it until later, see ya !

Comment: Cheers A. I'm having a play to see if I can add which number has been duplicated.

Comment: In the alert do `alert("A duplicated value: " + $(allFieldsForOrder[i-1]).val());`

Comment: Thanks for the changes to your script. The changes to using the input tag from within the form instead of the class event is really good. I'll look forward to seeing the other ideas. Also, thanks for alter script. I got it partly right. I didn't use the $ and enclose the i-1 in square brackets (I used round brackets).

Comment: Just a quick aside, is there a way to check for the duplicates when the submit button is clicked?

Comment: Yes it is, but will change the "logic" for the loop. Check this question/answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545941/jquery-on-submit-event

Comment: This answer could help you, but you will have to change the html you're generating: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614958/how-to-find-duplicate-values-in-array-using-jquery in order to use unique id's and a "group" name attribute "PositionNumber[]" or you could try with a couple of nested loops just o see if there's a value duplicated

Comment: @MartySmartyPants I just added another piece of code, it could help you.

Comment: Hope some one else can provide a better code I think the last one is my current-best

Comment: This just keeps getting better A. Thanks mate. You're a star.

Comment: Aaaarrrgggghhh! I spoke to soon. I'm getting the same alert popup (for duplicates and non-duplicates) and it states 'duplicated value:undefined'. I've tried changing the 'name' attribute to 'id' (as in the form the 'name' attribute is 'name="PositionNumber<%=counter %>"') but no change. Damn.

Comment: @MartySmartyPants mmm  weird I just tested and it worked, notice I changed the variable name to "exists" (from duplicated) and I used to get the duplicated value in tempArray: http://jsbin.com/rudagulo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Using your link to jsbin, when I run the code I get this in the console: `"Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[type='text'][name^='PositionNumber' (line 2)"`

Comment: Think I might have found the problem. The line `$("input[type='text'][name^='PositionNumber'").each(function(){` is missing a closing square bracket after 'PositionNumber'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent duplicate values in `RecordPosition` no matter how you insert/update them you can create a unique constraint this column

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_idx_RecordPosition ON tblStuff(RecordPosition);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c399d)** demo

Comment: Duplicates will be allowed. I just used the example to try to keep it all simple. Sorry. I've since added the whole code for the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do some client-side validation, you'd have to build an array that contains all the `RecordPosition` values.

Once you have that, you can check the array for duplicates. This has been asked a couple of times on SO: [Easiest way to find duplicate values in a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array)

Unfortunately I can't help any more than that because you don't include any code that shows how this is structured on your web page

Comment: I've added the whole page so you can see what I'm dealing with. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Check before inserting data in to data base

ex: recordposition value 3 --> 1 then pass value 1

SELECT * FROM tblStuff Where RecordPosition=1

if record exist then give message to user this position is exist